# An alternative to sleep () function in Delphi7

Tags: oop, delphi

```
IUfMessung = interface
['{6C258E04-BCC9-4349-912B-57A38F103570}']
    function MacheMessung(Ifl,Ufl: double): double;
end;

  TUFMessungMitHalten = class(TInterfacedObject,IUfMessung)
  private
    SWZeitHalten: double;
  public
    constructor Create(ASWZeitHalten: double); // Time to keep
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function MacheMessung(Ifl,Ufl: double): double; // do measuring 
  end; //   measuring with holding

  TUFMessungMitPause = class(TInterfacedObject,IUfMessung)
  private
    SWZeitPause: double;
    IfMin: double;
  public
    constructor Create(ASWZeitPause: double; AIfMin: double); // Time to keep + I[A]
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function MacheMessung(Ifl,Ufl: double): double;
  end; //   measuring with Pause

  TUFMessung = class(TInterfacedObject)    
  private
    //...
    Messungsart: IUfMessung;
  public
    procedure SetMessungsart(art: IUfMessung); // set measuring type
    procedure MessungsArtAswahl; // measuring type choice
    //...
  end; // do measuring

{ TUFMessung }
    procedure TUFMessung.MessungsArtAswahl;
    begin
        if  not FMitHalten and not FMitPause then  // Uf simple measuring
      begin
        SetMessungsart(TUFMessungEinfach.Create);
      end;

      if FMitHalten and not FMitPause then   // Uf with holding
      begin
        SetMessungsart(TUFMessungMitHalten.Create(FSWZeitHalten));
      end;

      if  not FMitHalten and FMitPause then  // Uf with pause
      begin
        SetMessungsart(TUFMessungMitPause.Create(FSWZeitPause,      FStartIf));
      end;
    end;

procedure TUFMessung.Start(StartIf, EndIf, StepIf, Uleer: double);
begin       
//...
  while not FIstFertig and FUfKannStart do
  begin
    Uf:= Messungsart.MacheMessung(Ifl, FUleer); // <= CALL the measuring
    //...
  end;
end;

{ TUFMessungMitHalten }
function TUFMessungMitHalten.MacheMessung(Ifl, Ufl: double): double;
var i_Zeit: integer;
begin    // Messvorgang
  hole_Uf(true, Ifl, Ufl); // set value
  i_Zeit:= Trunc(SWZeitHalten*1000);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(i_Zeit);  // wait Time ms.
  result:= hole_Uf(false, Ifl, Ufl); // measuring
end;

{ TUFMessungMitPause }
function TUFMessungMitPause.MacheMessung(Ifl, Ufl: double): double;
var i_Zeit: integer;
begin  // Messvorgang
  result:= hole_Uf(false, Ifl, Ufl); // measuring
  hole_Uf(true, IfMin, Ufl); // set value
  i_Zeit:= Trunc(SWZeitPause*1000);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  Sleep(i_Zeit);  // wait Time ms.
end;
```

I need to wait between the measuring processes for a time from 0 to 5 seconds. The solution with sleep () works well only till 1 second because I have in the program an RS232 communication and some timers. 
Is there an alternative to sleep () function so that the program precisely at this point a certain time is waiting for? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of waiting once for 5s, wait 5 times for 1s. Of course, that's blessing your current design. In an ideal world you would not use `Sleep` from the main thread and you would not ever call `ProcessMessages`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for your advice. I'll try it.

Comment: There's also MsgWaitForMultipleObjects but fundamentally pumping the queue away from main message loop as you do is opening yourself up for trouble unless you really understand the system deeply

Comment: Before I asked the question, I have read the article [link](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/02/blaise-pascal-magazine-rerun-7.html). But I do not know how to apply it to my task.

Answer (score 1):

As David says, there may be more elegant solutions for an ideal world, or if you are willing to get your hands dirty with low level device I/O and threading.  But until you have perhaps identified a more elegant solution, another approach would be to create your own time-out loop (a so called "busy loop") around **Application.ProcessMessages** to incorporate a "time-out" behaviour to return control to the caller after a specified time, processing messages in the meantime.

This might look something similar to this:

```
procedure ProcessMessagesFor(aTimeOut: Integer);
var
  start: Int64;
  elapsed: Integer;
begin
  start   := Trunc(Now * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  elapsed := 0;
  while elapsed < aTimeout do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    elapsed := Trunc(Now * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - start;
  end;
end;
```

This is also less than ideal however since **Application.ProcessMessages** will itself not return until any and *all* messages have been processed.  It would be better to check for the elapsed timeout after *each* message so that we can get back into the normal message loop as soon as possible.

**Application.ProcessMessages** simply calls a **ProcessMessage** function, but this is private to the **TApplication** class, so we cannot call this directly.

Fortunately, in Delphi 7, the **ProcessMessage** function is itself relatively simple and can be easily replicated within the timeout loop of a custom message processor.

Note that to do this we need to change a couple of **private** references (**fOnMessage** event handler for example) to the **public** equivalents and a handful of **TApplication** **protected** methods are involved which we obtain access to using a local sub-class and type-casting (a primitive pre-cursor to "class helpers" but which works in all versions of Delphi):

```
type
  // Creates a sub-class in scope which we can use in a typecast 
  //  to gain access to protected members of the target superclass

  TApplicationHelper = class(TApplication);


procedure ProcessMessagesFor(aTimeOut: Integer);
var
  start: Int64;
  elapsed: Integer;
  wait: Boolean;

  function ProcessMessage: Boolean;
  var
    msg: TMsg;
    handled: Boolean;
    app: TApplicationHelper;
  begin
    app := TApplicationHelper(Application);

    result := False;
    if PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
    begin
      result := True;
      if msg.Message <> WM_QUIT then
      begin
        handled := False;
        if Assigned(Application.OnMessage) then
          Application.OnMessage(msg, handled);

        if   not app.IsHintMsg(msg)
         and not handled
         and not app.IsMDIMsg(msg)
         and not app.IsKeyMsg(msg)
         and not app.IsDlgMsg(msg) then
        begin
          TranslateMessage(msg);
          DispatchMessage(msg);
        end;
      end
      else
        PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
    end;
  end;

begin
  wait  := FALSE; // We will not wait for messages initially
  start := Trunc(Now * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  SetTimer(0, 0, aTimeout, NIL); // Makes sure we get a message (WM_TIMER) at the end of the timeout period
  repeat
    if wait then
      WaitMessage;

    wait := NOT ProcessMessage; // If there was no message then we will wait for one next time around

    elapsed := Trunc(Now * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - start;

  until (elapsed >= aTimeout);
end;
```

I have used a crude multiplier and truncation of a **Now** date/time to obtain a millisecond precision elapsed time counter without having to deal with the wrap around (potential) issue with **GetTickCount**.  You may want to modify this to use a HPC or simply deal with the **GetTickCount** wrap-around.

We incorporate a **WaitMessage** mechanism so that if there are no messages to be processed then the code simply waits (efficiently) for any new messages.  To ensure that we are not waiting for messages beyond the timeout period, we initially set a timer event for the specified timeout.  This guarantees that a **WM_TIMER** message will arrive to signal the expiry of the timeout, which will "wake up" our message loop if it is still waiting when the timeout has expired.

Another thing to note is that **WM_QUIT** messages are re-posted to the message queue.  This is to ensure that these will be handled correctly when the **ProcessMessagesFor()** loop has timed out and messages are once again being handled by the main application message loop.

This function does not (strictly speaking) call **Application.ProcessMessages**, nor does it involve **Sleep()**, but it is still not an ideal solution being vulnerable to (potential) re-entrancy problems that having "inline" message loops always creates.  These can be managed by controlling user interaction with parts of the UI that might cause such re-entrancy problems (i.e. disable forms or controls while processing is completed).

But even without such refinements it may keep you going with your current problem unless and until a more ideal solution is found.

Comment: Also a busy loop, and thus definitely to be avoided

Comment: The problem as stated is to wait for a period of time while continuing to process other application messages (specifically timer messages but the response to these *could* involve other messages so all messages must be handled other than **WM_QUIT** as explained).  There is no polling or other activities other than message handling and "timeout" evaluation.  As such it is just a specialisation of *processing messages until quitting time*.  So if *this* is a busy loop that is "*definitely to be avoided*" then so is *any* message loop, including the one that drives *all VCL forms applications*.

Comment: No. They aren't busy. They yield the processor until messages arrive. Why do you think your vcl app consumes no cou when it is idle? Because GetMessage blocks.

Comment: The [Delphi 7] VCL message loop does not call **GetMessage**.  The VCL consumes no CPU because (the Delphi VCL) message loop calls **WaitMessage** (after firing an *OnIdle* event) *if* **PeekMessage** finds no messages.  You're right tho, this is the difference between the original function and the VCL loop.  However, it is simple enough to incorporate a **WaitMessage** mechanism and a timer to ensure that the function will "wake up" at the end of the timeout period.  I've updated the function accordingly.  *Now* it is the same as the VCL loop.  :)

Comment: That's another way to do it for sure. I'd forgotten about that unconventional approach. Not sure why they don't use the traditional loop. Anyway no matter. The point is clear. Busy loops are no good though. Asker seems happy with his busy loop though. Oh well.

Comment: The answer to "Why" is the *OnIdle* event which would be impossible if the message loop simply blocked on **GetMessage**.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I knew that once, but have long since forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your source, but if you're combining RS232 and waiting, Sleep sounds like a bad idea. The best you could do is have the system respond to you *as soon as data comes in*, not blindly wait for it. Depending on what you use to do RS232 communication, you should look for something like [SetCommTimeouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437.aspx) and fine-tune how read operations behave: if the data is not in yet, stall for the receive timeout, and after that respond that zero bytes were received. This is best done from a dedicated thread (which might take a little learning to get a hang of). Another option is using asynchronous calls (which also take a little learning to get a hang of).

Answer (score 0):

Create you own sleep function:

```
procedure MySleep (const uSec: UInt);

var uStart : UInt;

begin
  uStart := GetTickCount;

  while (GetTickCount < (uStart + (uSec * 1000))) do
  begin
    Sleep (250);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end
end;
```

Comment: Note that the result of `GetTickCount()` wraps around after 2^32 milliseconds. Depending on the compiler settings this procedure will then either raise an exception or fail silently. Better to use `GetTickCount64()`

Comment: You are right. But Delphi 7 does not have an import for "GetTickCount64" and it is not clear which target OS is used. "GetTickCount64" is only available on Vista and better. But here's the declaration:
function GetTickCount64 : Int64; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetTickCount64';

Comment: @OlafHess Thank you for your answer. It works. I'm going to try it later with devices again.

Comment: @OlafHess Why is 'Application.ProcessMessages;' calling after sleep and not before?

Comment: @genakust: No particular reason. If you want to, just change the order.

Comment: Busy wait, don't do this unless you are cold

Comment: As David Heffernan pointed out, calling "Sleep(0)" is going to saturate one CPU core. To avoid this use "Sleep (250)" or some other value. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Good to see that the sympathy upvoters are here. It wouldn't do to signal through voting that an answer is no good. No sir. Most important is that posters aren't put off posting, no matter how bad the advice is.

Comment: @Olaf: If `GetTickCount64()` is not an option then at least the logic of the comparison needs to be fixed. Given the right conditions (like `uStart` being `$FFFFFFFF - 1000` and a one second wait) this is not much more than a badly implemented infinite loop.

Comment: And what if you want to sleep for 60 seconds, and in the meantime user wishes to terminate the app? There's no exit in this loop...